# Only run two tasks if a previous task fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm currently using Ansible 2.2 to script out and deploy a syslog server in AWS. One prerequisite that we have is to have a persistent EBS volume that will hold logs for a month until we ship them off to S3. So if we need to tear down syslog and redeploy it via Ansible, we would just reattach it to the newly deployed server and it'll still have the previous logs on it. That part is fine, I've got that handled.

My issue is where I'm trying to make this whole task entirely automated where if the EBS volume doesn't exist for X, Y, or Z reason, we create a new EBS volume (got it), attach, (got it), create partition (got it), format (got it), and mount it (got it). Hopefully the following code will help understand that:

```
- name: Create log partition
  shell: /bin/echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw" | sudo fdisk /dev/xvdb


- name: Format log partition
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: "/dev/xvdb1"


- name: Mount log drive
  mount:
    name: /log
    src: "/dev/xvdb1"
    fstype: ext4
    state: mounted
```

That code is working perfectly, but I realized that while running this and reattaching an existing EBS volume, I would still repartition and format the volume, deleting my historical data and starting from scratch, which is very not good.

What I am hoping to do accomplish is some sort of check before partitioning and formatting to make sure we're not wiping out data. I think the best way about it would be to attempt mounting the drive and if it succeeds then skip the partitioning and formatting. But if the drive fails to mount, then do the partitioning, formatting, and mounting.

I'm fairly new to Ansible so I'm open to any ideas and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at [conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) and [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html)

Look at this example playbook:

Here we try to create a fs on /dev/xvdb1 partition. If it's absent or contains another filesystem (be careful with that!) - register "result" will contain info about that failed task. After that we define a block with your action which will be executed only if your previous task has failed.

```
- name: create new fs on device
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: /dev/xvdb1
  register: result
  ignore_errors: true

- block:
  - name: Create log partition
    shell: /bin/echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw" | sudo fdisk /dev/xvdb


  - name: Format log partition
    filesystem:
      fstype: ext4
      dev: "/dev/xvdb1"


  - name: Mount log drive
    mount:
      name: /log
      src: "/dev/xvdb1"
      fstype: ext4
      state: mounted
  when: result|failed
```

You might want to adjust this to avoid wiping other valid filesystems by parsing `result.stderr`, but that's another story. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using raw block device without partition, this piece of code is fairly idempotent:

```
- name: Make filesystem
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: /dev/xvdb

- name: Mount log drive
  mount:
    name: /log
    src: /dev/xvdb
    fstype: ext4
    state: mounted
```

Comment: With this, if the ext4 filesystem already exists on the device, does it recreate it and wipe data? Or does it essentially say "oh, it's already ext4, let's skip this"?

Comment: The latter. If ext4 is there, Ansible will do nothing, just say 'ok'.